# Form plugin is submitting all forms at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Recently I have created a plugin that is a form validation plugin. It has several different options in it, one of which is `onSubmit`. The `onSubmit` option overrides your normal submit functionality and prevents any default action, allowing it to work for ajax calls. What I ran into today is that when I have multiple instances of it on the same page it will attempt to submit all instances at once, even though I'm not hitting their submit buttons. I figured since I'm using the `this` keyword for each instance, that wouldn't be a problem. I was wrong apparently. Now I do not know what to do about this, and how to make it only function for what ever instance I'm working with at that time.

Below is the entire code for the plugin. and an example of the forms that I am using. I am extremely confused and really need some help figuring out a solution to this.

**forms**

```
<form id='addSlipForm'>
    <section class='form-group col-xs-2'>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='trip' placeholder='Trip'/>
    </section>
    <section class='form-group col-xs-2'>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='trip_date' placeholder='Trip Date'/>
    </section>
    <section class='form-group col-xs-2'>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='facility' placeholder='Facility'/>
    </section>
    <section class='form-group col-xs-2'>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='minutes' placeholder='Minutes Late'/>
    </section>
    <section class='form-group col-xs-2'>   
        <div class='input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker'>
            <input type='text' class='form-control' id='scheduled_arrival' placeholder='Scheduled Arrival'>
            <span class='input-group-addon'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span></span>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class='form-group col-xs-2'>
        <section class='btn-group'>
            <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Add</button>
            <button type='button' class='btn btn-info'>Add and New</button>
            <button type='reset' class='btn btn-danger'>Clear</button>
        </section>
    </section>
</form>

<form id='searchBar' class='navbar-form navbar-right'>
    <section class='form-group'>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='contract' placeholder='Contract #'/> 
    </section>
    <section class='form-group'>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='startDate' placeholder='Start Date'/> 
    </section>
    <section class='form-group'>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='endDate' placeholder='End Date'/> 
    </section>
    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Filter Slips</button>
</form>
```

**#searchBar js call**

```
$('#searchBar').validator({
    controls : {
        contract : {
            validate : 'notEmpty'
        },
        startDate : {
            validate : 'isDateTime',
            dateFormat : 'm/d/Y'
        },
        endDate : {
            validate : 'isDateTime',
            dateFormat : 'm/d/Y'
        }
    },
    onSubmit : function(){
        var contract__id = $('#searchBar').find('#contract').val();
        var start_date = $('#searchBar').find('#startDate').val();
        var end_date = $('#searchBar').find('#endDate').val();
        koolajax.callback(getLateSlipTable(contract__id, start_date, end_date), function getLateSlipTableDone(response){
            if(!response.errors){
                $('#main').removeClass('hidden');
                $('#contractName').data('id', response.contract__id);
                $('#contractName').html(response.contract);
                $('#lateSlipTable > tbody').html(response.table_rows);
            }else{
                bootbox.alert(response.error_message);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**#addSlipForm js call**

```
$('#addSlipForm').validator({
    controls : {
        trip : {
            validate : 'notEmpty'
        },
        trip_date : {
            validate : ['notEmpty', 'isDateTime'],
            dateFormat : 'm/d/Y'
        },
        facility : {
            validate : 'notEmpty'
        },
        minutes_late : {
            validate : ['notEmpty', 'isDigit']
        },
        scheduled_arrival : {
            validate : 'notEmpty'
        }
    },
    onSubmit : function(){


    }
});
```

**validator.js**

The code is massive so in leu of posting that, source is located here

https://github.com/MarkHill89/validator/blob/master/validator.js

**NOTES**

You'll see under `#addSlipForm js call` that the `onSubmit` is blank, that is because I haven't submitted a response function for it yet, but you can see where my confusion is coming from at this point as well. So it clearly has nothing to do with the actually submission itself. It is something that is being done before the submission, which is obvious but I figured I was clearly state it here for relevance.

**EDIT**

Here is a link to the fiddle that replicates this problem as requested
http://jsfiddle.net/8bh0nv76/1/

Comment: I don't think you can expect anyone to read through all this code and figure out what your problem is. You need to post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: I'm very aware of this, however, I know that the second I post the way the validator pugin is called, someone is going to ask for me to post the source code for the validator.js file, so it's kind of a catch 22 don't you think?

Comment: @MarkHill What he's asking is for you to dumb down the validator plugin to only the pieces needed to recreate the problem. surely you don't need all of the validation code in place for it to recreate the problem.

Comment: Is `validator.js` an open source plugin? If so...it's likely to have been tested and a link to it would suffice

Comment: It is open source, I created it, and you can find the source on Github here https://github.com/MarkHill89/validator/blob/master/validator.js

Comment: so the problem is in the plugin itself?

Comment: `var selectors = [];` how is this used, before i try to dig through this to find it? As written, it would be shared between all elements using this plugin.

Comment: This is correct, maybe I have worded my question wrong. I can edit it if need be

Comment: What if you change your submit buttons to just regular buttons, bind to click events on the buttons, and submit the specific form when the validation passes?

Comment: @KevinB `selectors` is an array that houses all the id's or class selectors for the controls within a form. In the source code you can find it on line `373`

Comment: @devlincarnate tried that, still the same

Comment: Here: https://github.com/MarkHill89/validator/blob/master/validator.js#L482 you are causing all instances of the same selector to use the same settings object. this isn't affecting your current case, but it will affect, for example, $(".vform") where there are multiple `.vform` elements. **this is a different problem, just pointing it out while i'm here**

Comment: @KevinB is there a way around that?

Comment: Yes, create a copy of the object using `$.extend({},options,true);`

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that would cause the problem you are describing.

Comment: create a demo that replicates problem and just prevent the submit events

Comment: @kevinB would you be willing to submit that as a change to my code and I will approve it. Also I will elaborate more I suppose, because there has to be something off here. What's going on is when I submit, it's going through each and every form control and attempting to validate it. Is it possible that I'm actually pushing all the selectors into one giant array, and I mean the selector array is global is it not?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the problem.

Comment: all the instance insulation will be inside `return this.each` closure

Comment: @charlietfl fiddle is active

Comment: So you'll need to store that array somewhere where each element will have it's own selectors array. This is complicated by the fact that the array is needed by the reset method, which wouldn't have access to it if it was defined inside of the init method. You'll need to store it somewhere where you can gain access to it outside, such as on the element's .data(). What i would do is store it in the `settings` object, and store the whole settings object on the element's .data() for easy access.

Comment: Here it is fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/8bh0nv76/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you're creating an Array named `selectors` globally inside your plugin, and only once - when the plugin is inserted into the page. Then, when someone call the `validator` method (to init your plugin), you push the selectors into this Array, and you use it for almost everything in your code, including the `onSubmit`.

So, you will face lots of problems with that, since you're not creating an instance of some constructor you should have created (with all the specific properties inside it) for each time someone initializes your plugin for other selectors.

You have the same problem with the variable `_defaults`, that you declare globally either.

Kevin B fixed the `selectors` problem (thanks!), take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/8bh0nv76/2/

Comment: `default` isn't  generally a problem in plugins because you extend each instance using default as base to new object. But as Kevin pointed out that `extend` isn't happening. Also can set page defaults when it is exposed

Comment: You all did a fantastic job! Thank you so much for the collaboration it really helped me figure this out and I learned a few new things at the same time!